Saving one's rebbe's possessions
The Gemorah in Baba Metzia 33 states that, when seeing one's rebbe vs. one's father's possessions, the Rebbe takes precedence. The rebbe brings him to Olam HaBah and his father Olam haZeh.
The items of one's Rebbe would take precedence over the items of one's father. Would the monetary value of the item be any factor in this chesbon? What about different keddusha levels of the items, e.g., his father's megillah verses his rebbe's Mezuza?

Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Yoel!

What puzzles me about this is if the rebbe's precedence is because he brings him to olam haha then why would the example be concerning physical items be first returned to his Rebbe?

HisxRebbe teaches him Torah and Mitzvis which gives him zechosim (merits) for entry to Olam HaBah.

Due to his teachings he becomes like a father even more so and out of kavod he should first chase after his Rebbe's items.
